# Help with simplifying p,q, logic and proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How do I simplify the following:

$ (p \wedge q) \vee q$

$ p \to (p \to q)$

$\neg (\neg p \wedge \neg q)$

Comment: Formatting tips here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.

Comment: When presenting a problem in a Question here, you should give some context to let Readers assess where you found a difficulty.  If you have not even attempted a problem and ask without digesting what parts might be easy, you may not get a sympathetic response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this page: [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

As regards the first one, by Absorption 2:
$(p \wedge q) \vee q\equiv q$.

As regards the second one, note that $p\to q\equiv \neg p \vee q$, hence
$$p \to (p \to q)\equiv \neg p \vee (p \to q)\equiv \neg p \vee (\neg p \vee q)\equiv (\neg p \vee \neg p) \vee q\equiv\neg p \vee q\equiv p \to q.$$

As regards the third one, use the [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Thus
$$\neg (\neg p \wedge \neg q)\equiv p \vee q.$$

Comment: Can you explain the second one? How do you explain p→q≡¬p∨q

Comment: @Huskey 4 They have the same Truth table. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional

Comment: @Huskey Any further doubt?

Comment: I understand now, thanks for the help.